# How to compare the values of all field at a time on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML structure like the following,

```js
$(".zip-save").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var isFormValid = true;
var zip_start = $('.zip-first').val();
var zip_end = $('.zip-last').val();
console.log("start = " + zip_start + ",end = " + zip_end);
if (zip_start > zip_end) {
  $('.zip-last').css('border-color', 'rgba(218, 71, 58, 0.5)');
  $(this).parents('div').before("<p>zip-to value must be greater than zip-from</p>");
} else {
  $('.zip-last').css('border-color', 'rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.12)');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
</br>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
</br>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
</br>
<button class="zip-save">Save</button>
```

And on save button click function, I want to check all of these first zip field value is less than the last zip field value,

I could do the same for only the first `<tr>`, but how to do that for all of them at a time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. My first observation is that you have multiple elements with the same class, `zip-first` and `zip-last`. When you call `.val()` on these it will get one of the values not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through those table rows, whereas you were only grabbing the values for the first row. I gave the table a classname and then looped through the tr tags. Also note this syntax: `+$(this).find('.zip-first').val()` - that little plus sign converts this string into a number so I can make the comparison. Also, I made a div at the bottom to hold the error.

```js
$(".zip-save").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let isFormValid = true;
  $('.zip-table tr').each(function() {
    let zip_start = +$(this).find('.zip-first').val()
    let zip_end = +$(this).find('.zip-last').val();
    // console.log("start = " + zip_start + ",end = " + zip_end);
    if (zip_start > zip_end) {
      $(this).find('.zip-last').css('border-color', 'rgba(218, 71, 58, 0.5)');
      $('.error').html("zip-to value must be greater than zip-from");
    } else {
      $(this).find('.zip-last').css('border-color', 'rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.12)');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='zip-table'>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
  <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class='error'></div>
<button class='zip-save'>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(".zip-save").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var isFormValid = true;
  var zip_start;
  var zip_end;
  $("table tr").each(function(index, elem) {
    zip_start = parseInt($(".zip-first", elem).val());
    zip_end = parseInt($(".zip-last", elem).val());
    if (zip_start > zip_end) {
      console.log(zip_start, zip_end, "invalid");
      $('.zip-last', elem).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    } else {
      console.log(zip_start, zip_end, "valid");
      $('.zip-last', elem).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input.valid {
  border-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.12;
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: rgba(218, 71, 58, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code OF" class="form-control zip-first" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" placeholder="ZIP code BIS" class="form-control  zip-last" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button class="zip-save">Save</button>
```

I have cleaned up your HTML Table. You should not include elements like `<br>` inside table rows. I also wrapped it with the proper `<table>` element.

As was suggested, you must iterate over each row and examine the Inputs in that row. You can do this with `$(elem).find(".zip-first")` or the shorthand, `$(".zip-first", elem)`. Input elements return a String Value, so for better comparison, it is best to cast it as an Integer.

It is sometimes better to add or remove classes as needed. You can also use `.toggleClass("invalid")` to easily add / remove a single class.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/find/
- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/